# I want to count distinct values in multiple column and show the results in separate rows

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm kinda new to SQL and working on a dataset where I need to count 1,0 or Y,N flags in each of the column and give a resultant count column.
To give an example, here's what the data looks like:

| Flag1 | Flag2 | Flag3 | Flag4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| N | Y | N | Y |
| Y | Y | Y | Y |
| N | N | N | N |
| Y | Y | N | N |

Here's what I want:

| Flag1 | Flag2 | Flag3 | Flag4 | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| N |  |  |  | 2 |
| Y |  |  |  | 2 |
|  | N |  |  | 1 |
|  | Y |  |  | 3 |
|  |  | N |  | 3 |
|  |  | Y |  | 1 |
|  |  |  | N | 2 |
|  |  |  | Y | 2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a union between all the possible combinations:

```
select 'N' as Flag1, NULL as Flag2, NULL as Flag3, NULL as Flag4, (select count(*) from table_name where Flag1='N') as count
union all
select 'Y', NULL, NULL, NULL, (select count(*) from table_name where Flag1='Y') as count

union all

select NULL, 'N', NULL, NULL, (select count(*) from table_name where Flag2='N') as count
union all
select NULL, 'Y', NULL, NULL, (select count(*) from table_name where Flag2='Y') as count

union all

select NULL, NULL, 'N', NULL, (select count(*) from table_name where Flag3='N') as count
union all
select NULL, NULL, 'Y', NULL, (select count(*) from table_name where Flag3='Y') as count

union all

select NULL, NULL, NULL, 'N', (select count(*) from table_name where Flag4='N') as count
union all
select NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Y', (select count(*) from table_name where Flag4='Y') as count
```

Comment: Thanks @Zakaria this worked. I had to make a few more tweaks with the data I was working with, however, the concept of NULL-ing and UNION-ing the results helped me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler way to calculate this using the [GROUP BY GROUPING SETS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/group-by-grouping-sets.html#group-by-grouping-sets) function:

```sql
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT * 
    FROM (VALUES 
  ('N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y'),
  ('Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'),
  ('N', 'N', 'N', 'N'),
  ('Y', 'Y', 'N', 'N')) T(Flag1, Flag2, Flag3, Flag4)
)
SELECT Flag1, Flag2, Flag3, Flag4, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
  FROM sample_data
 GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (Flag1, Flag2, Flag3, Flag4)
 ORDER BY Flag1, Flag2, Flag3, Flag4;
```

Result:

| FLAG1 | FLAG2 | FLAG3 | FLAG4 | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| N |  |  |  | 2 |
| Y |  |  |  | 2 |
|  | N |  |  | 1 |
|  | Y |  |  | 3 |
|  |  | N |  | 3 |
|  |  | Y |  | 1 |
|  |  |  | N | 2 |
|  |  |  | Y | 2 |

Comment: excellent application of grouping sets .